# Dockerized Ganache-cli + HdWallet Provider?

Tags: ganache-cli, hdwalletprovider

Does anyone have any experience connecting an instance of HdWalletProvider to a dockerized Ganache-Cli? Having trouble connecting with http://0.0.0.0:8545, or ganache-cli:8545, or anything other form of host I can think of. I'm new to Docker as well (snippet attached)

```
var provider = new HDWalletProvider({mnemonic: teamsMnemonic, providerOrUrl: "http://0.0.0.0:8545", addressIndex: 0, numberOfAddresses:10, shareNone:false});
```

```
version: "3"
services:
mongo:
image: mongo
ports:
 - 27017:27017

executor:
build:
context: https://github.com/zach-is-my-name/Aion.git#docker
depends\_on:

  - mongo
  - ganache-cli
labels: 
  purpose: "run the Aion system executor"
  platform: "node.js"

truffle-test-suite:
build: .
depends\_on:

  - ganache-cli
labels: 
  purpose: "run the GoalZapp test suite"
  platform: "node.js"
  framework: "truffle"

ganache-cli:
image: trufflesuite/ganache-cli:latest
command: bash "ganache-cli -h http://0.0.0.0:8545 -f https://sandbox.truffleteams.com/de77b065-c9a7-4c8b-9fe9-0e507a623f9a"
ports:
- 8545:8545
labels: 
  purpose: "run the virtual ethereum network for testing, hosting Aion contract"
  platform: "node.js"
```

**Update** [Gist with formatted docker-compose.yml](https://gist.github.com/zach-is-my-name/514768d66741e15b4566aa81e3faaf5e)

Comment: Your current `docker-compose.yml` is invalid. Please fix that first so we can try to reproduce it.

Comment: It’s just bad formatting from the copy/paste, no?

Comment: Sure, but it would be helpful if you provided a valid (properly formatted) config.

Comment: @Morten see update with gist link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you for referring the ganache comment, It seems to work fine for you now with adding the port with the container's name `ganache:8545` to further refer this URL.
As per forwarding rules defined here https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

I am just a new user and already learning a lot from stackexchange, thank you for being with me and helping me solve your issue.

---

old...

Please take a look at this line bash...

```
"ganache-cli -h http://0.0.0.0:8545 -f https://sandbox.truffleteams.com/de77b065-c9a7-4c8b-9fe9-0e507a623f9a"
```

The host value does not look correct.
[image]

As per docs, it doesn't seem to have a protocol or port defined with it. Try to just use `0.0.0.0`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113548/discussion-on-answer-by-jeevanjot-dockerized-ganache-cli-hdwallet-provider).